# Pgadmin export to html

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to find out how I can create a html table file out of the results i'm getting from my query in pgadmin 3. I've seen somebody doing that before but I can't find the setting; I've found the convert to csv setting, but I want html.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the *Query Editor* window, after you've done a query which returned a set of rows, you want to go to **File > Quick Report**.

This will bring up a dialog where you can choose *XHTML* (which sounds like the one you would want) or *XML*, and whether to include a default style sheet, along with choosing the file name and a couple of other things, such as including the *SQL* in the report.

Comment: Euhm it works for smaller queries. But I've got also a query with near 4 million rows. And it just crashes. Can it maybe be done from the psql terminal?

Comment: Found the solution here: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/how-to-get-desired-html-format-output-td5719354.html Thanks!